# truncate text with double quotes in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using the below snippet to truncate text and it is working fine, except in cases where the text contains double quotes.

```
function truncateText(str, len) {
return (str.length > len ? $.trim(str).substring(0, len).split(" ").slice(0,-1).join("") :str);   
}
```

for example: 
len = 10
str = "helllllllo worlllld" - working fine.

but in case like this:

len = 10
str = "hellllll"o worlllld" - not working as expected.

I have tried to do the followings with no success:

```
str = str.replace('"', '\"');
 str = str.replace('"', '&quot');
 str = str.replace('"', '\x22');
```

Comment: not working as expected means for example:
len = 15;
str1 = 'home - did go' - result: 'home - did go'
str2 = 'hom"e - home' - result: 'hom"e'

Comment: what would "it's not working as expected" exactly refer to - what are you expecting, what is the actual output?

Answer (score 1):

The declaration:

`var str = "helllll"o world";`

is not valid javascript. You need to escape the middle quote for it to run properly.

Try:

`var str = "helllll\"o world";`

or

`var str = 'helllll"o world';`

Comment: this is just example, in my real code i don't know what is the value of str because it is variable that can change.

Comment: When the function is called with: truncateText("helllll\"o world", 10), what output are you expecting?

Comment: not working as expected means for example: len = 15; str1 = 'home - did go' - result: 'home - did go' str2 = 'hom"e - home' - result: 'hom"e'

Comment: OK, but the result for your second example should be 'hom"e - home', correct?

Comment: your function works as expected for me. are you seeing any javascript errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in your javascript function

```
return '"'+str.trim(len).replace('"','')+'"';
```

I tried for this and it worked.

```
<input type=button onclick='truncateText("Hello\" world",10)'/>
```

This gives me Hello world (without the " inbetween )

Comment: but i want to display the quoets.

Comment: ok then you can add quotes before returning the string         return '"'+str.trim(len).replace('"','')+'"';

Answer (score 0):

Use below function. It may be used as you want. 
I changed truncateText() function too,

```
 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js " type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
    function truncateText(str, len) {
        return (str.length > len ? $.trim(str).substring(0, len) : str);
    }    
    var mystr = "helllllll\"o wor\"lllld";
    mystr = mystr.replace(/\"/g, '');         
    alert(truncateText(mystr,10)); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not in the javascript function but it turns out that i had to do html decode on the server side to the returning string.